# Google Model Viewer is not displaying output

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, model-viewer

So, I used Google's Model Viewer for displaying GLB files. But it seems to be throwing these errors:

```
>Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Untitled.glb' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

>Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

>model-viewer.js:50001 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at co.load (model-viewer.js:36818:3)
    at Mh.load (model-viewer.js:44762:10)
    at model-viewer.js:49881:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at model-viewer.js:49880:12
    at Jc.preload (model-viewer.js:49988:34)
    at Jc.load (model-viewer.js:50018:20)
    at n (model-viewer.js:51575:73)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Bu.setSource (model-viewer.js:51572:26)
(anonymous) @ model-viewer.js:50001
```

My code >

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

<!-- Use it like any other HTML element -->
<model-viewer style = "width:1050px;height:1050px;" src="Untitled.glb"  camera-controls ></model-viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

And I got the code from this website [Model Viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/)

Comment: check the path of your file once. Because your code is perfectly alright

Comment: My files are perfect. I mean I have the HTML file and the GLB file in the same directory

Comment: are you using live server extension by VS Code?

Comment: No I just directly opened it.

Comment: Try this solution https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/disable-same-origin-policy/

Comment: Any way to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: try using this extension atleast https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: <model-viewer style = "width:1050px;height:1050px;" src="Untitled.glb"  crossorigin="anonymous" camera-controls ></model-viewer>try this also instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to solve it is by converting the glb file to a DataURI and then loading it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

<!-- Use it like any other HTML element -->
<model-viewer style = "width:1050px;height:1050px;" id = "glb" crossorigin="anonymous" camera-controls ></model-viewer>
<script>
    document.getElementById('glb').src= "/*--DATA URI HERE--*/"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This is just done with JS

Answer (score 0):

Use a CDN instead direct loading from `file://` is not allowed [[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). You can use [glitch](https://glitch.com/) their file system is similar to what you would normally use plus it provides free online hosting and auto-saving options. Here is a [model-viewer example](https://model-viewer.glitch.me/) on glitch.